# C++ sorting vector strings not working

Tags: c++, string, vector, compare

For some reason I cannot get this sort the names correctly. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it? As far as I can tell the problem is that the strings are not compared correctly. I have tried string comparisons before, and I know this kind of code should work. It really has me stumped.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void sortNames(vector<string> &);

void main()
{
    vector<string> namesList;
    ifstream namesFile;
    namesFile.open("Names.txt");

    // Make sure the file exists.
    if (namesFile)
    {
        // Get the names from the file.
        string name;
        while (getline(namesFile, name))
            namesList.push_back(name);

        // Sort the imported names.
        sortNames(namesList);

        for (int i = 0; i < namesList.size(); i++)
            cout << namesList[i] << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Data files are missing";
    }

    namesFile.close();
}

void sortNames(vector<string> &list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        // Find the lowest value after i.
        int lowIndex = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++)
        {
            string name = list[i];
            string name2 = list[j];

            if (name > name2)
                lowIndex = j;
        }

        // Flip the elements if there was a value lower than i.
        if (i != lowIndex)
        {
            string temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[lowIndex];
            list[lowIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do know you can sort a vector using `std::sort`?

Comment: This is a learning exercise in a textbook to learn sorting and searching algorithms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the problem: this line

```
string name = list[i];
```

should be

```
string name = list[lowIndex];
```

Your current implementation compares the element at `j` not to the smallest string that you have found so far, but to the string at index `i`. That is incorrect, because it does not find the smallest remaining string: instead, it finds the last string in the `vector` that is smaller than the current element at index `i`, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

rather than `string name = list[i];`, you want `string name = list[lowIndex];`